# Proving inequalities by using induction: $n^2 \ge n+1$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, inequality, induction

For all $n\ge 2$ prove $n^2 \ge n+1$ by using induction.

Here is my attempt at the problem.

Base case: $n=2$, $2^2 > 2+1$, $4>3$

Inductive step:

$p(k) = k^2 \gt k+1$

$p(k+1)=(k+1)^2 \gt (k+1)+1=k^2+2k+1 \gt k+2$

This is where I got stuck. This type of problem is not like the ones that sum up a number of terms. Am I allowed to subtract 1 from both sides of the inequality? If that is allowed I can say that $k^2 \gt k$ and it is proven.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT:

Substitute what you got from the hypothesis and you'll get:

$$k^2 + 2k + 1 > 3k + 2 > k+2$$

Which is equivalent to:

$$(k+1)^2 > 3k + 2 > (k+1) + 1$$

Hence the proof.

Comment: What do you mean by substitute what I got from the hypothesis? I don't understand where the $3k+2$ came from.

Comment: In the second step, i.e. the inductive hypothesis you assumed that $k^2 > k + 1$ holds for some number, all we need now is to prove that this holds for $(k+1)^2 > (k+1) + 1$. You can use your assumption that $k^2 > k + 1$. Just substitute now.

Comment: I see how you got $3k+2$ now but why would it make sense to substitute something that is less than $k^2$ into the right hand side when we are trying to prove that it is greater than $k+2$?

Comment: Because if we substitute something less than $k^2$ and prove that it's greater than $k+2$, then means $k^2 > k+2$. Here's more general: Let $f(k) > g(k)$ and $g(k) > h(k)$, then we can conclude $f(k) > h(k)$. Now in our case $f(k) = k^2, g(k) = 3k + 2, h(k) = k + 2$

Comment: That makes sense, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing well, but have put together what I would call a backwards proof.  A proof should be a sequence of statements, each of which follows from the preceding ones.

So, for your inductive step:
\begin{eqnarray}
k^2 & > & k+1 \quad (\textrm{This is $p(k)$, the induction hypothesis})\\ 
k^2+1 & > & k+2 \\ 
k^2+2k+1 & > & k^2+1 \\
k^2+2k+1 & > & k+2 \\
(k+1)^2 & > & (k+1) +1 \quad (\textrm{This is $p(k+1)$})
\end{eqnarray}